# how to display the menu name in drop-down menu dynamically in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

this is my index.html file

```
  <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Reports</li>
                    <li>
                           <div class="buttons pull-right">
                                <a href="{% url 'report:reporttest' %}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        <a href="{% url 'report:reporttwo' %}">Report one</a>
                    </li>
                    {% if name %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'report:add' %}">{{name}}</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </li>
```

the view.py file

```
def reportone(request):
return render(request, 'report_one.html')
def reporttwo(request):
return render(request, 'report_two.html')
def reporttest(request):
return render(request, 'add_report.html')

def add(request):

   if request.method == "POST":
       #rept=ReportName.objects.all()
       #rept=ReportName()
       src=request.POST.get('src')
       width=request.POST.get('width')
       height=request.POST.get('height')
       name=request.POST.get('name')
       #context={'rept':rept}
       #if request.method == "POST":
       return render(request, 'report_one.html', {'src':src, 'width':width, 'height':height, 'name':name})
   else:
       return render(request, 'report_one.html')
```

i have created report successfully....but i want the report name which i was creating will display on the dropdown menu ....
using the above code i can able to see the created report name in the dropdown but the problem is when we click on the report name which is shown in the dropdown is not showing the created report and report name will also remove from the dropdown menu ....
i want all the report that i created before will show in the dropdown after the page get reload or reopen the page
i believe i have to store data in the database
but is that possible to display the report in one new page and the report name in dropdown without storing in the database

Answer (score 0):

A way to to store the report names without saving it into the database would be to save the report names in a list, so in your view.py create a list call it reports for example and then whenever a new report is created append it to the list and pass the list in your context and then in your html file, add a for loop which iterates over the list ND then displays each list. For further explanation, contact me on my Gmail redamerhi@gmail.com

Comment: tried with list but now working ...please any one provide the code of view.py file and html